# How to create a function that prints or returns results of another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, random

I've created a function (`p_r`) that will either `print` or `return` the results of functions.

I'm doing this for running tests. (print shows the output, return will spit out the values but doesn't print the output).
- Python noob; so, let me know if there is an easier way of doing this, like a "verbose" or testing keyword. I've been on this project for days.

**Modules required...**

```
import random
```

**Variables:**

```
yt_url = '' #url of either a video or playlist [user input]
printr_return = True
yt_url1 = 'https://youtu.be/WaGRTixwkSQ'
yt_url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FhCd_HO_AD-22-Csv-vYlhLoKlAY3Zt'
```

**The function:**

```
#Switches between printing or returning data, depending on printr_return
#''' 
def p_r (statement, printr_return):
    if printr_return is True:
        print (statement)
    else:
        return (statement)
#'''
```

---

**The problem:**

I don't understand why I get a `NoneType` when I use `p_r` in the following function:

```
#Choses between the two urls above and outputs yt_url
#'''
def random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2):
    rnt = random.choice([1,2])
    if rnt == 1:
        yt_url = yt_url1
    if rnt == 2:
        yt_url = yt_url2
    p_r (yt_url, False)    #-- what's wrong here?
    #return yt_url          #-- but this works
#'''
```

**Run it:**

```
yt_url = random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2) #returns NoneType if I use p_r
p_r ('Running test on url...%s' % (yt_url), True) #This works...
```

Comment: Edit your post to include the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: It seems like you would be better served by a logging tool, such as the built-in [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). You can't write a function that returns on behalf of its caller, and having your functions conditionally not return things seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Regardless of this specific example working or not, there is no point in a function that only returns or prints the argument it receives **as is**.

Comment: What's error message?

Comment: Sorry @mohammad and @John Gordon it's actually just a `NoneType`, but that causes errors when I try to fetch the video because there's no url output. I edited the question.

Comment: You are not returning anything at random_urltest!

Comment: @user2357112 Yep - logging is what I need. The official documentation confused me, but I found a [quick start guide](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/logging/) that was a good starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was *"trying to reinvent the wheel"*...

[user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943559/how-to-create-a-function-that-prints-or-returns-results-of-another-function#comment74919764_43943559) gave the best answer to my overall problem (although the answers from [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43943837/1947026) and [mohammad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43943791/1947026) solve my question directly)

I can use the built-in [`logging module`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) to debug/test - and [disable logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.disable).

The details of how to use the module are extensive, but I referenced [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/logging/) and made a quick code change to show how it works...

**The changes include**:

- adding the `logging module`
- creating a `logging` configuration as `logger`
- replacing my `p_r` function with the `logger` object
- Simplified the `random_urltest` function

---

**Imports:**

```
import random
import logging
```

---

**Creates a logger configuration**: [Formats info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

---

**Variables:**

```
yt_url = '' #url of either a video or playlist [user input]
yt_url1 = 'https://youtu.be/WaGRTixwkSQ'
yt_url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FhCd_HO_AD-22-Csv-vYlhLoKlAY3Zt'
```

**Function:**

```
#Choses between the two urls above and outputs yt_url
#'''
def random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2):
     yt_url = random.choice([yt_url1, yt_url2])
     logger.debug('Running test on url...%s',yt_url)
     return yt_url
#'''
```

---

**Run it:**

```
random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2)
```

---

**Output:** : url will switch between url1 and url2

```
2017-05-12 12:48:13,186 root         DEBUG    Running test on url...https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FhCd_HO_AD-22-Csv-vYlhLoKlAY3Zt
[Finished in 0.118s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting at the end

return (p_r (yt_url, False))

instead of just running the function

Comment: Yep. That did it! Although, having looked at some other replies about the [`logging module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) that may kill the need for the function I created. I'll research that and later decide which solution is best for my needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2):
     rnt = random.choice([1,2])
     if rnt == 1:
         yt_url = yt_url1
     if rnt == 2:
         yt_url = yt_url2
     val = p_r (yt_url, False)
     if val:
         return val
```

Comment: Is `if val:` a shorter, reverse alternative to `if val is None:`?

Comment: they are equivalent because also if val = 0 then "if val" is not evaluated. but in your case they are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

You clearly expect the `random_urltest()` function to return a value:

```
yt_url = random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2)
```

But the function does not return anything!  As @bell-_-0001 suggested, instead of just *calling* `p_r()`, you need to *return* its value:

```
def random_urltest (yt_url1, yt_url2):
    rnt = random.choice([1,2])
    if rnt == 1:
        yt_url = yt_url1
    if rnt == 2:
        yt_url = yt_url2
    return p_r (yt_url, False)
```

Comment: Ah! That solution works ~ I'm also going to look into the [`logging module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) that @user2357112 mentioned. That may work better